# Read data from csv into list of class objects - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, object

I'm having trouble figuring this out. Basically I have a .csv file that has 7 employees with their first and last names, employee ID, dept #, and job title. My goal is for `def readFile(employees)` to accept an empty List (called employees), open the file for reading, and load all the employees from the file into a List of employee objects (employees). I already have my class built as:

```
class Employee:
def __init__(self, fname, lname, eid, dept, title):
    self.__firstName = fname
    self.__lastName = lname
    self.__employeeID = int(eid)
    self.__department = int(dept)
    self.__title = title
```

I have a couple other class methods, but basically I don't quite understand how to properly load the file into a list of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I opened the file and then read a line from it, stripping the \n and splitting my data. I used a while loop to keep reading lines, as long as it wasn't an empty line, and appended it to my empty list. I also had to split the first indexed item as it was first and last name together in the same string and I needed them separate.

```
def readFile(employees):
    with open("employees.csv", "r") as f:
        line = f.readline().strip().split(",")
        while line != ['']:
            line = line[0].split(" ") + line[1:]
            employees.append(Employee(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]))
            line = f.readline().strip().split(",")
```

It most likely could be written better and more pythonic but it does what I need it to do.

Answer (score -1):

Why don’t use pandas. So you define an employee pandas object and use their index for select each employee and the name of each column for select an specific employee attribute.